# Selecting date in format dd/mm/yyyy from nchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have date in column of `nchar(255)` datatype in this format

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

Now I want to change it into

```
   dd/mm/yyyy
```

I don't think that `CONVERT` help me in this as I have tried different queries like below

```
SELECT CONVERT(NCHAR(20), col1, 103) from table1
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), col1, 103) from table1
select Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,col1,101),103) from table1
```

In my view 103 which is in UK format converts only from `yyyy-mm-dd`

So I tried to `CAST` my col1 but I get an error.

Am I missing something? Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Your last query is right check the demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/911847/2

Comment: but that is giving me out-of-range error.How to handle that leftover spaces in my nchar(255) field?

Comment: nchar(255) also working http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d61c/4

Comment: You shouldn't change it to another format - you should change it to an **appropriate data type** like `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` !

Comment: It was not me who did this. The person who worked before me on this project did this. He wasnt aware of this.

Comment: Lol. `nchar(255)` is probably the most inappropriate datatype I have yet seen for dates. It means that each date is taking 510 bytes. Compare this with 3 bytes for `date` or 8 for `datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.(Just in case anyone wants to know what is the solution)

There was no such problem with the query i was using. i.e.

```
select Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,col1,101),103) from table1
```

The problem was with my nchar field. 
It was having a special character (in my case a space) in every entry which was giving "out-of-range" error when tried to convert or cast.

So removing Special character(a space) solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in two expiicit steps.  First, convert the string to a date using the 101 format (which is mm/dd/yyyy).  Then explicitly convert the date back to a string using 103 (which is dd/mm/yyyy):

```
select convert(varchar(255), convert(date, datecol, 101), 103)
```

Two points.  First, I don't think the result needs to be `nvarchar()` (the string only consists of numbers and a slash).  Second, always include a length when using `varchar()` in SQL Server.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44c71/1) is a little SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that i had a space before every date. thats was causing this problem

Comment: They say `nchar` rather than `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, col1, 101), 103)
```

Comment: it is giving error "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"

Comment: @gRaWEty can you try this: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/13/2010', 101), 103)`

Comment: can that error because of the size of the nchar field i.e. i have nchar(255) but have only data of mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @gRaWEty You said that you have this format `mm/dd/yyyy` not this `dd/mm/yyyy`. The problem is about format not length.

Comment: yes format is mm/dd/yyyy only . but it is giving error. but if i give hard coded value its working fine. so what am i missing?

Comment: Probably there are some values inside the column that cause the overflow during the conversion. That's the only reason. Try to execute it using `TOP(1)`.

Comment: yes u r right. a space is present before every date. thanks a lot for your help. should i delete this question as it may waste others time????

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Select convert(varchar(15), cast('01/26/2015' as datetime), 103) as FormattedDate
```

Where, **'01/26/2015'** is your **col1**

Edited Answer:

```
Select convert(nchar(255), cast(col1 as datetime), 103) as FormattedDate From table1
```

Where table1 is your table.

Comment: when i replace '01/26/2015' with col1 it is giving me out-of-range error. How to handle that leftover spaces in my nchar(255) field?

Comment: Check SQL Fiddle result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d61c/2 It seems to be working fine. Still I am checking on your error.

Comment: I have not used hardcode value in SQL Fiddle. Check it. I have inserted it in a table and used col1 as in select query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was that i had a space before every date. thats was causing this problem

Comment: now that third query of mine works fine. Thanks a lot paresh.

Comment: should i delete this question as i cannot mark any answer correct and it will waste others time too ???